# How can I convert a word file to Adobe illustrator or HPGL file?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, file-format, microsoft-word

How can I save or convert a star image that I have taken from word shapes into Adobe Illustrator or an HPGL file?

I need to upload it to an engraving machine and these are the only two files types that it will allow me to upload.

I am not from a techie background, so please advise me in a simplistic language.

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE. I edited your answer a bit, it's not necessary TO SHOUT in here. If you have more questions about how the site works, please check the [help].

Answer (score 2):

You can copypaste things from Word, via PowerPoint and form there to Illustrator*. Or you can export the page as PDF and read that into Illustrator. You can also save your drawing as a EMF file and read that to Illustrator.

You can also make it a HPGL file by installing a HPGL printer driver and then print to file.

* You can copypaste to Illustrator direct but not always as vectors. Powerpoint does not have this problem.